# Using result from select query as variable on sub-query

Tags: soql

Sorry for the title, I could not come up with a better one.

Basically, I have the following query

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Name FROM Prod__c WHERE Id = Case.Id) FROM Case limit 20
```

So what I want to achieve is to use the result Id from the query on the sub-query.
It is some internal SF Id, and the name I need is in Prod__c.
When trying it like this I get the following error:

```
Bind variables only allowed in Apex code
```

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible. But any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce does automatically the filter on the sub-queries provided that you use a relationship field to fetch them (Lookup / Master Detail).

Assume you have an sObject called `Prod__c` and also a relationship field from `Prod__c` to `Case` with Api name `Case__c` (and which "Child Relationship Name" is `Prods` (You can check chat on the detail of the relationship field)). If that is the case, you can :

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Name from Prods__r) FROM Case LIMIT 20
```

In this case `Prods__r` is the `Child Relationship Name`  + `__r`. Note that standard relationships do not need the `__r`

#### Edit after the chat

The sObject Case has a relationship to `Prod__c` through `Case_Product__c`.
He wants to get all cases that have a specific Prod__c (by Id), so the pseudo code would be

```
Id prodId = 'whateverId';
List<Case> casesForProduct = [SELECT Subject, Case_Product__r.Name FROM Case WHERE Case_Product__c = :prodId];

// additionally consider ordering and limiting the results
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is with the usage of a variable for the where clause. I can get data from that object if  I use a fix value. But here I do a query for Id on Case, and would require that result in the subquery to Prod__c as a where limit

Comment: salesforce automatically filters the Prod__c records that are related to each of the Case records retrieved, you don't need an extra where clause. If you want to compare things between those, you could have a formula field on Prod__c that compares data from Case and Prod__c and filter it in the sub-query

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. I get Didn't understand relationship when trying with both __c or __r. I'm also just a user of the API, so not able to make any changes.

Comment: If you have access to the schema, go to the sObject Prod__c, go to the field list, then go to the detail of the lookup / Master-Detail that points to Case, and you'll find that you have to put before the `__r` inside the section called `Child Relationship Name` (you don't need to change anything, just being able to read it. Otherwise... you could describe the sobject and figure it out there)

Comment: Sadly that is beyond my SF knowledge, I'm just a user of the frontend. I can access the Id if I append it to our SF URL, but I don't see anyway how to access more details of this object from there.

Comment: Do you have access to workbench? workbench.developerforce.com

Comment: I was able to login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116111/discussion-between-sergio-alcocer-and-derchris).

Comment: Thanks again, we solved it in chat. Turned out I had to use the following in my query: Case_Product__r.Name from Case, Case_Product__c was the original field which game me the Id I needed the name of.